# how to find a array of occurence of a character in a string

Tags: php, string

I am searching for a function in PHP to return the array of position of a character in a string.

Inputing those parameters "hello world", 'o' would return (4,7).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can check this http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php#92849 or http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php#87061, there are custom strpos functions to find all occurrences

Answer (score 9):

No looping needed

```
$str = 'Hello World';
$letter='o';
$letterPositions = array_keys(array_intersect(str_split($str),array($letter)));

var_dump($letterPositions);
```

Comment: +1 Nice, gotta to get more fluent with these array functions.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP no such function exists (AFAIK) that does what you're looking for, but you can make use of [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/preg_match_all) to get offsets of a substring pattern:

```
$str = "hello world";

$r = preg_match_all('/o/', $str, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
foreach($matches[0] as &$match) $match = $match[1];
list($matches) = $matches;
unset($match);

var_dump($matches);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  int(4)
  [1]=>
  int(7)
}
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/VAI3nL)

Answer (score 0):

```
function searchPositions($text, $needle = ''){
    $positions = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($text);$i++){
        if($text[$i] == $needle){
            $positions[] = $i;
        }
    }
    return $positions;
}

print_r(searchPositions('Hello world!', 'o'));
```

will do.