# Need Help in building a logic

Tags: php

I need to get all the positions of a character in a string in a form of an array. I know about the php function `strpos()` but it does not accept an array as an argument.

This is required:

```
$name = "australia";            //string that needs to be searched
$positions_to_find_for = "a";   // Find all positions of character "a" in an array 
$positions_array = [0,5,8];     // This should be the output that says character "a" comes at positions 0, 5 and 8 in string "australia"
```

**Question:** What Loops can help me build a function that can help me achieve the required output?

Comment: but you are not sending an array as an argument.

Comment: Mihai is right, PHP strings are *not* arrays.

Comment: I don't think the OP suggested otherwise. He's asking for a `strpos` variant that returns the position of all occurrences of the needle, not just the first. It's a good question.

Comment: i think `loop` is not a big deal here...

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to find a array of occurence of a character in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8799799/how-to-find-a-array-of-occurence-of-a-character-in-a-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `for` to loop that string:

```
$name = "australia";
$container = array();
$search = 'a';
for($i=0; $i<strlen($name); $i++){
    if($name[$i] == $search) $container[] = $i;
}

print_r($container);

/*
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 5
    [2] => 8
)
*/
```

[Codepad Example](http://codepad.org/Z7Clh4NZ)

Comment: @Minhai lorga Thank you very much friend, did not know it wasn't something too simple ... I am new to programming, therefore I was finding it difficult to build such logic.

Answer (score 1):

No loops necessary

```
$str = 'australia';
$letter='a';
$letterPositions = array_keys(
    array_intersect(
        str_split($str),
        array($letter)
    )
);

var_dump($letterPositions);
```